# What must be done on backend server and what on client

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, architecture

I have situation,

I need to download some data let's say X gigs(huge data) on client machine using browser's native js. Then I need to run compute extensive job tasks(tensorFlow like computation) on client and finally show results to actual uses.

I need to understand things like how can I architect such requirement, I am UI engineer I have never done this things in life.

If someone can suggest end 2 end things this will save my life.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean you want to communicate between the client and your server, having the extensive work be done on the server and sent to the client, or are you just dealing with client code that's requesting data and doing the work itself?

Comment: Just realized you mentioned "backend server" in the title. I'll answer in a second.

Comment: @Ace This can be done on backend, so which approach is right?

Comment: Depends; if the work is resource intensive, or involves sensitive data, you'd want to do it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can communicate between a client and a server.

**1**

The first one is the more traditional way of sending xhr requests from the client who waits for a response.

On Server:

```
app.post('/path', (req, res) => {
    const json = req.body;
    //do work
    const resp = {some: 'data'};
    res.json(resp);
}
```

On Frontend

```
fetch('/path', {
  method: 'post',
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
  headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' }
})
.then(res => res.json()) // get json data out of response object
.then(json = > {
    // do something with response json
}
```

**2**

This second method uses a package called Socket.IO to communicate via websockets. Both the client and server can send and listen to specific events using the following simple pattern.

```
socket.emit('event_name', optional_json);
socket.on('event_name', res => useResponse(res));
```

You may look at these resources to learn about these methods of communicating between client and server:

- [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)
- [Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)
- [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/)

Comment: Nice explanation, but the question is about scale not the basic solution, how you can send let say 100 GB data on a client, where would you store it on a browser, how would you process that data that is computer extensive(needs lot of heavy math) GPU oriented. as JS is not good at computational extensive things (single threaded, non-blocking)

Comment: Does that X GB of data need to be downloaded to the client? You said it needs to be processed and the result be shown to the user. It can be processed on the server and the result be sent to the client.

Comment: You can read the question again, and I know that it can be done on server, I need to know how this can be done on client, best ways and optimum strategy.